# How to get stack to always use the latest LTS when starting a new project?

Tags: haskell, ghc, haskell-stack

It is a bit of a hassle to always have to go to [stackage.org](http://stackage.org) to check what the latest LTS version is and then type in the command:

```
stack new projectname --resolver=lts-X.XX
```

Is there a way to get stack to always discover the latest LTS and use that for new projects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use:

```
stack new projectname --resolver=lts
```

Similarly, you can use `--resolver=lts-5` to get the latest in the 5 series, or `--resolver=nightly` for the latest nightly. For more information, see [the Stack user guide](http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE.html#resolvers-and-changing-your-compiler-version).